# allocating memory for sprintf problem?

Tags: c

the problem is i dunno how long the string will be, so i dunno how much should i allocate for my data...

```
char *Data = malloc(1024*1024);  //???????
sprintf(Data, "%s %s", Data1, Data2);
```

Data1 and Data2 varies in Size from time to time.... from very very long to very small
i was wondering if there is away to use sprintf without allocating memory or something, since the allocated memory could be small sometime..

thanks

Comment: Care to elaborate as to what Data1/Data2 are? I would probably go with using [sizeof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w557fh7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) though.

Comment: Convention. In C, generally everything is lowercase. In OO languages, words starting with capitals generally mean classes.

Comment: Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase

Comment: Exact duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295013/using-sprintf-without-a-manually-allocated-buffer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many C runtime libraries (for instance, GNU's glibc and FreeBSD's (and NetBSD's and OpenBSD's and OS X's) libc) provide [`asprintf`](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Dynamic-Output.html), which combines `malloc` and `sprintf` into a single call.

```
char *Data = NULL;
asprintf(&data, "%s %s", Data1, Data2);
```

Assuming the return value indicates success, enough space has been dynamically allocated for the string, which you should `free` when no longer used.

Comment: Well, it wouldn't be in the "standard library" even if it's provided in the same package as the standard library on the target platform. Better would be "Many C runtime libraries come with the nonstandard "asprintf", which combines ...."/

Answer (score 5):

Since data1 and data2 seem to be strings just use strlen() and allocate just the amount of memory you actually need.

```
char *data = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(data1) + strlen(data2) + 1));
```

Comment: no, sorry, i didnt point well, they are called functions, data1 and data2, and there are like 6 more, i cant call each function twice to calculate their length then call them again to print them with sprintf
sprintf(Data, "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s", function1, function2, function3, function4, function5, function6, function7, function8, function9)

Comment: @killercode: So `Data1` and `Data2` are functions that return `char *`?  If so, save the result to another pointer (e.g., `char *tmp1 = Data1(), *tmp2 = Data2(); size_t len1 = strlen(tmp1), len2 = strlen(tmp2); char *data = malloc(len1 + len2 + 1);`, etc.).

Comment: You should calculate the size of allocated string as: sizeof(char) * (strlen(data1) + strlen(data2) + 2. One for the space character that separates concatenated strings and the second for the null character that terminates the string.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `sprintf()` use `snprintf()` which will never overflow the buffer (you tell it how large the buffer is).  `snprintf()` will also tell you how big the buffer needs to be to avoid truncation of the result.

Note that MSVC doesn't have an `snprintf()` but includes the similar `_snprintf()`.  However that function has at least 2 differences from the standard:

- it might leave the result unterminated
- it won't tell you how large of a buffer you need if it does truncate

If you're using MSVC, you might want to consider using [Holger Weiss' `snprintf()` implementation](http://www.jhweiss.de/software/snprintf.html) (which has a liberal license).

Answer (score 1):

Not possible.  You always have to allocate the buffer used by sprintf/printf

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

...But you don't need to allocate every single time your code is run.  Depending on whether or not your program is multi threaded, how frequently this section of code is going to be run and how big the biggest possible string you expect is, you are probably better off allocating the a single buffer of "biggest possible size" once and using a safe version of sprintf like snprintf to fill it. (Guards against overruns).  Or you could conditionally reallocate the buffer if the size you require exceeds the current buffer size.

For example, if you are using C++ and your code above lives inside a method, you could change your Data allocation line to:

```
static char *Data = malloc(1024*1024);
```

The static keyword used within a method promises that your local variable will only be initialized once - the first time the line is invoked and will live beyond the scope of that method call.

If you are using C, then your buffer could be a global (I'm not a fan of this), or you could pass a pointer to a locally scoped Data buffer around.  I'm sure real C programmers have better suggestions on how to do this kind of thing.

I know it seems inefficient to just have a giant buffer hanging around that you almost never take full advantage of, but it turns out that for most applications, the overhead of allocation is a much bigger issue than the possibility running out of heap space.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the strlen functions for the string sizes?

```
char *buf = malloc(strlen(Data1) + strlen(Data2) + 2); // 2 for space and \0
sprintf(buf, "%s %s", Data1, Data2);
```

This solves the problem where you need to figure out the size of Data1 and Data2 at runtime.